# Verification: Give a definition of a $G$-Set so that it may be viewed as an algebra

Tags: proof-verification, universal-algebra

A $G$-Set for those who may not be familiar with the terminology is as follows:

Let $G$ be a group and $S$ be a set. $G$ acts on $S$ define by the map $\star : G \times S \to S $ where $e \star s = s$ and $g\star (h \star s) = gh \star s, \forall s \in S, g,h \in G $ and so $\langle  S, \star \rangle$ is a $G$-set

An algebra is a pair $\langle A, F \rangle $ where $A$ is the universe and $F$ is the family of operations on $A$

Now I need to give a definition that presents $G$-sets as an algebra which are equivalent to the above definition of a $G$-set

I thought one such definition would be :

$\langle S, \star \rangle =\langle S, \star_{g},\star_{h} ... \rangle$ (***) where we have $\star = \{\star_{g} : g \in G\}$

$\star_{g} s = g \star s, \forall g \in G, \forall s \in S$

That is for all elements of $G$, each element becomes associated with a unary operation in the signature of (***) .

so we would have $\star_{e}s = e \star s = s, \forall s \in S$
for $\star_{g}(\star_hs) = \star_g(h \star s) = g \star (h \star s)) = hg (\star s) = \star_{gh}s$

This seems valid as we have our universe $S$ with a signature of operations and can axiomatize it by the above equations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, what you describe is the standard way of describing a $G$-set as an algebra. This is for fixed $G$. You can also give equational axioms for the theory of group actions (where the group is also allowed to vary), but you have to use [multi-sorted logic](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-sorted_logic).

Answer (score 2):

Your definition is fine, although using $\star$ for what is (as you point out) a unary operation maybe isn't ideal.

For a group $G$ acting on a set $X$, define the $G$-set $\langle X, \overline{G}\rangle$ to be the algebra with universe $X$ and operations $\overline{G} = \{\bar{g} \mid g \in G\}$, one (unary) operation for each $g\in G$.  Then $\bar{g}x$ would denote the action of the group element $g$ on the element $x\in X$.  As you point out, we require $\bar{e} = \operatorname{id}_X$ (the identity function on $X$), and $\overline{gh} = \bar{g} \circ \bar{h}$.

Essentially, this is what you have already figured out for yourself, in slightly different notation.

See also Bill Lampe's very nice and concise [presentation of $G$-sets as universal algebras](http://www.math.hawaii.edu/~ralph/Classes/619/611_07_G-sets.pdf), which develops some of the properties of $G$-sets from this perspective.

Answer (score -1):

You can take a $\Bbb{K}$-vector space $V$ (for some field $\Bbb{K}$), whose dimension is equal to the cardinality of the set $S$. That is, for each $s \in S$, you have a basis element $e_s \in V$. Then your construction is essentially the so-called "group algebra" $\Bbb{K}[G]$, realized as a sub-algebra of the endomorphisms of $V$. So what you call $\star_g$ is realized concretely here as the linear map defined by

$$ \star_g(e_s) = e_{g \star s} $$

So what I'm getting at is that $\mathrm{End}_\Bbb{K}(V)$ is an algebra, and the maps $\star_g$ generate a sub-algebra.

Comment: I am not sure this is what I would be after as I need to define the $G$-set as an algebra which its definition is equivalent to the standard definition i.e. a $G$-set being a set acted on by a group $G$

Comment: An algebra is a vector space with a multiplication. Where are you getting the vague definition of algebra which you quote above? If $S$ were an algebra, you'd have to define what the product of two elements of $S$ was. What I was describing was more making $G$ into an algebra.

Comment: in this context an algebra is a pair $\langle A, F \rangle$ where $A$ is the universe (a nonempty set) and $F$ is the family of fundamental operations on $A$. I get the definition from the text I am using on Universal Algebra

Comment: I'm not familiar with this definition of an "algebra". Sorry for any confusion.